# type null is not a subtype of string in modal route

Tags: flutter, dart, null

```
import 'package:ecommerce_shop/providers/product.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_shop/providers/products.dart';

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'edit-product';
  const EditProductScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditProductScreenState createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _edittedProduct = Product(
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    imageUrl: '',
    price: 0,
  );
  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
    'id': '',
  };
  var _isInit = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String;
      if (productId != null) {
        _edittedProduct =
            Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).findById(productId);
        _initValues = {
          'id': _edittedProduct.id,
          'title': _edittedProduct.title,
          'description': _edittedProduct.description,
          'price': _edittedProduct.price.toString(),
          // 'imageUrl': _editedProduct.imageUrl,
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _edittedProduct.imageUrl;
      }
    }
    // if (_isInit) {

    //   // var productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments ?? "";
    //   // // var productId =
    //   // // ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String ?? " ";
    //   // // productId ??= " ";
    //   // // final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    //   // //  print('$productId   **********************************************');
    //   // _edittedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(
    //   //   context,
    //   //   listen: false,
    //   // ).findById(productId as String);
    // }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (_imageUrlController.text.isEmpty ||
        !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('http') ||
        !_imageUrlController.text.startsWith('https')) {
      return;
    }
    if (!_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
    _imageUrlController.dispose();
    _imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();
  }

  void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProduct(_edittedProduct);
    // _form.currentState!.save();
    // if (_edittedProduct.id != '') {
    //   Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
    //       .updateProduct(_edittedProduct.id!, _edittedProduct);
    // } else {

    // }

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Edit Product'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: _saveForm,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _form,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Title',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'please provide a value';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _edittedProduct = Product(
                      id: _edittedProduct.id,
                      isFavourite: _edittedProduct.isFavourite,
                      title: value!,
                      description: _edittedProduct.description,
                      imageUrl: _edittedProduct.imageUrl,
                      price: _edittedProduct.price);
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Price',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionFocusNode);
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'please enter a price';
                  }
                  if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                    return 'Please enter a valid number';
                  }
                  if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                    return 'please enter a number greater than 0';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _edittedProduct = Product(
                    id: _edittedProduct.id,
                    isFavourite: _edittedProduct.isFavourite,
                    title: _edittedProduct.title,
                    description: _edittedProduct.description,
                    imageUrl: _edittedProduct.imageUrl,
                    price: double.parse(value!),
                  );
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Description',
                ),
                maxLines: 3,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'please enter a description';
                  }
                  if (value.length < 10) {
                    return 'should be atleast 10 characters long';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _edittedProduct = Product(
                      id: _edittedProduct.id,
                      isFavourite: _edittedProduct.isFavourite,
                      title: _edittedProduct.title,
                      description: value!,
                      imageUrl: _edittedProduct.imageUrl,
                      price: _edittedProduct.price);
                },
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8,
                      right: 10,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                          ? const Text('Enter a Url ')
                          : FittedBox(
                              child: Image.network(
                                _imageUrlController.text,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      // initialValue: _initValues['imageUrl'],
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image Url'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      controller: _imageUrlController,
                      focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        _saveForm();
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _edittedProduct = Product(
                            id: _edittedProduct.id,
                            isFavourite: _edittedProduct.isFavourite,
                            title: _edittedProduct.title,
                            description: _edittedProduct.description,
                            imageUrl: value!,
                            price: _edittedProduct.price);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code and I am getting the error as null is not a subtype of string But I couldn't get how to resolve it, if you want my complete project files for checking
it is on https://github.com/SaivigneshAdepu20/ecommerce_shop.Actually I have shared the arguments in provider as id in product item screen which is available in my Github account.

Comment: which line is getting error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly contents do you expect? If it i s List or similar, try:

```
final List<String> files = ModalRoute
          .of(context)
          .settings
          .arguments as List<String>;
```

Also it may be that you try calling .of(context) too soon. Try closing it in

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero,(){
      //Here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm following the same tutorial and this is code below fix it

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit == true) {
      final String productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments == null ? '':ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
      if (productId.isEmpty != true) {
        final product =
            Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).findById(productId!);
        _editProduct = product;
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editProduct.title,
          'price': _editProduct.price.toString(),
          'description': _editProduct.description,
          'imageUrl': _editProduct.imageUrl
        };
        _imageUrlController.text= _editProduct.imageUrl;
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```